# bing map freezes browser by adding 8000 pushpins

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Bing map in my site freezes browser due to loading of 8000 properties(pushpins) even though I used clustering concept. Please give me a solution for this scenario.(I've used pure javascript in coding.)

Comment: You need to provide your JavaScript code to help us help you. Please provide this first.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. There simply is too much data. The map control on it's own can handle about 1000 pushpins before there are too many DOM elements on the page and the browser slows down. Client side clustering good to about 5,000 (sometimes more depending on browser and your computer).

You have two options, move to server side clustering which will calculate the clusters on the fly and constantly send down the cluster groups for the current map view, or When you  rasterize your data (turn your data into an image).

I have a white paper on how to do this [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D35222484A76A01!361218&authkey=!AMEJsKW8h_HUbOg&ithint=file%2cpdf).

You can find the code samples [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D35222484A76A01!323177&authkey=!AId01rJ-JPDPZMw&ithint=file%2czip)